# Cannot aggregate total with a CALL with UNION

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get the total rows of my union but it only shows a total of 1 for each (rather than 2)

```
CALL {
    OPTIONAL MATCH 
        (a:Account { 
                id : $account_id 
            })
        -[:MEMBER]->
        (n:Workspace)
    RETURN n
    
    UNION

    OPTIONAL MATCH
        (n:Workspace { 
            account_id: $account_id 
        })
    RETURN n
}
WITH n, COUNT(n) AS total
RETURN n, total
```

Is it possible to aggregate the `total`?

Current non-`UNION` query (works)

```
            OPTIONAL MATCH 
                (a:Account { 
                        id : $account_id 
                    })
                -[:MEMBER]->
                (n:Workspace)
            WITH 
                COLLECT(n) AS nodes, 
                COUNT(n) AS total
            OPTIONAL MATCH
                (n:Workspace { 
                    account_id: $account_id 
                })
            WITH
                nodes + COLLECT(n) AS n,
                total + COUNT(n) AS total
            UNWIND n AS node
            WITH 
                node, 
                total
                    SKIP $skip
                    LIMIT $limit
            WITH 
                COLLECT(node) AS results, 
                total
            RETURN results, total
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `RETURN sum(total)` ?

Comment: oh and use UNION ALL to not remove duplicates

Comment: @MichaelHunger I want the duplicates removed. So the two queries should return different sets of results, which is why I want to `COUNT` the final aggregation of the `UNION`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you get two rows with a result of 1 instead of 1 row with the result of 2. When aggregating in cypher it does implied groupby, meaning that all the columns in the `WITH` or `RETURN` statement will be used in the groupby statement by default. So if you want to return only a total count you can use:

```
CALL {
    OPTIONAL MATCH 
        (a:Account { 
                id : $account_id 
            })
        -[:MEMBER]->
        (n:Workspace)
    RETURN n
    
    UNION

    OPTIONAL MATCH
        (n:Workspace { 
            account_id: $account_id 
        })
    RETURN n
}
WITH n
RETURN count(*) as total
```

Comment: Your answer made me realize that I forgot to call `COLLECT` on my nodes, which was what I had previously but forgot to re-include

Comment: Actually, it isn't working as I expected now, since I want to apply a `SKIP` and `LIMIT` for pagination reasons. I have another query I'm currently using that's not using `UNION`, though I am still curious if it's possible to do what I want (return both results and the total/count). Updated answer to include it.

Comment: trying to understand UNION a bit more. Seeing if it's possible to convert my non-union query into using UNION to produce same results